# SQL Value being changed to 1 and not the value given

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this might be the wrong place to post or ask this but i am having problems with this code, i am trying to make it change the sql field 'selected' to the $link but all it does it change it to '1'. I don't see anything wrong with the code?

```
   <?php

   require "../requires/php/steam.php";

$link = $_GET['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("*****","battlefield","*****","battlefield");
// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$authserver = bcsub( SteamID(), '76561197960265728' ) & 1;
    $authid = ( bcsub( SteamID(), '76561197960265728' ) - $authserver ) / 2;
    $steamid = "STEAM_0:$authserver:$authid";




mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE dogtags SET selected=$link
WHERE steamid32='$steamid'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I may be wrong but looks like your `$link` variable contains 1 as in your code `$link = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()`ing your `$link` variable right after initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of your `$link` does not match the value that is inserted into the `selected` column, this means that the datatype of the `selected` column can not accommodate the value.

As from your query, it looks like `selected` is a numerical type, in most likelihood it's declared as `TINYINT(1)`. Inserting any value other than zero, will set the value of this column to 1.